# Change text at many indices in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I have the following sample from a long query and trying to build a tool:

```
var str =" SELECT 
             'Capital Return' AS Portfolio_Classification
            , '(Gross)' AS Portfolio_Type
            , '0.21%' AS Portfolio_Value
            , '' AS Benchmarks_Classification
            , '' AS Benchmarks_Comment
            , '' AS Benchmarks_Value
FROM hfhgjdfgj
WHERE number= 3
        UNION
        SELECT 
             'Capital Return' AS Portfolio_Classification
            , '(Net)' AS Portfolio_Type
            , '0.21%' AS Portfolio_Value
            , '' AS Benchmarks_Classification
            , '' AS Benchmarks_Comment
            , '' AS Benchmarks_Value"
FROM asdfasdf
WHERE 1=1
```

I am trying to put single quotes after the strings that appear after the AS as follows:

```
     var str =" SELECT 
             'Capital Return' AS 'Portfolio_Classification'
            , '(Gross)' AS 'Portfolio_Type'
            , '0.21%' AS 'Portfolio_Value'
            , '' AS 'Benchmarks_Classification'
            , '' AS 'Benchmarks_Comment'
            , '' AS 'Benchmarks_Value'
FROM hfhgjdfgj
WHERE number= 3
        UNION
        SELECT 
             'Capital Return' AS 'Portfolio_Classification'
            , '(Net)' AS 'Portfolio_Type'
            , '0.21%' AS 'Portfolio_Value'
            , '' AS 'Benchmarks_Classification'
            , '' AS 'Benchmarks_Comment'
            , '' AS 'Benchmarks_Value'"
FROM asdfasdf
WHERE 1=1
```

I have tried getting all indexes of "AS"+1 and setting this to "AS '"  but still stuck with the problem of the end of the words not also having single quotes. Looked through Lodash and Vanilla Javascript but going in loops.

Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
var str =" SELECT 'Capital Return' AS Portfolio_Classification , '(Gross)' AS Portfolio_Type , '0.21%' AS Portfolio_Value , '' AS Benchmarks_Classification , '' AS Benchmarks_Comment , '' AS Benchmarks_Value FROM hfhgjdfgj WHERE number= 3 UNION SELECT 'Capital Return' AS Portfolio_Classification , '(Net)' AS Portfolio_Type , '0.21%' AS Portfolio_Value , '' AS Benchmarks_Classification , '' AS Benchmarks_Comment , '' AS Benchmarks_Value";

str = str.split(' ');

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(i != 0 && str[i-1] == "AS"){
        str[i] = '\'' + str[i] + '\'';
    }
}

str = str.join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RegExp. Search for the word "as", one or multiple spaces and a word consisting of [a-z0-9_-]. Then return quoted result.

```js
var str = `SELECT 
             'Capital Return' AS Portfolio_Classification
            , '(Gross)' AS Portfolio_Type
            , '0.21%' AS Portfolio_Value
            , '' AS Benchmarks_Classification
            , '' AS Benchmarks_Comment
            , '' AS Benchmarks_Value
FROM hfhgjdfgj
WHERE number= 3
        UNION
        SELECT 
             'Capital Return' AS Portfolio_Classification
            , '(Net)' AS Portfolio_Type
            , '0.21%' AS Portfolio_Value
            , '' AS Benchmarks_Classification
            , '' AS Benchmarks_Comment
            , '' AS Benchmarks_Value"
FROM asdfasdf
WHERE 1=1
`;

var result = str.replace(/as\s+([a-z0-9_-]+)/gi, function(_, s) {
  return "AS '" + s + "'";
});

console.log(result);
```